# Callback is null on delete method

Tags: java, spring, angular

I'm trying to send a string message from my spring back-end to my angular front-end when a object's been deleted.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String deleteMovie(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
    return "String";
}
```

This code does nothing but return a string.

In the angular app I have this function in the controller:

```
deleteMovie(id: number): void {
  this._dataService.deleteMovie(id)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this.movies = this.movies.filter(movie => movie.id !== id);
  },
  error => () => {
      'something went wrong';
  },
  () => {
    // console.log(this.movies);
  });
}
```

And this is the service:

```
public deleteMovie(id: number) {
    return this.http.get('/api/movies/' + id, {headers: this.getToken()});
}
```

When I run the code the console logs `null`. When I check the network tab I can see that the delete return doesn't have a `request payload` so I think that's why the console logs `null`.

// why is the question getting downvoted? :/

Comment: In angular service path variable send like '/report/viewUser/:id'.

Comment: Did the `deleteMovie` in spring is hitting? Put break point and check.

Answer (score 0):

Did the deleteMovie in spring is hitting? Put break point and check.  If yes then you should be use `.map();` because of subscription.

```
 return this.http.get('/api/movies/' + id)
            .map((res: Any) => {
                return res;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            });
```